# Como guardar la informacion de un URL para luego usarla?

Tags: python, variables, botón, url, bot

hola necesito ayuda con esto
Deseo leer un URL de un boton y luego usar una parte de ese mensaje y mandarlo a otro bot

```
@events.register(events.NewMessage(chats='AAAAAAA'))
async def mob_handler(event):
  client = event.client
  if 'AAAAAAA' in event.raw_text:
  async for message in client.iter_messages('AAAAAAAA', limit=1, from_user='AAAAAAA'):
   await message.click(0)
  await asyncio.sleep(0.2)
  idxq = event.message.text.find("url")
  cant = event.message.text[idxq+2:idxq+27]
  await event.respond("/" + (str)(cant))
```

para que entiendan mejor el boton tiene el siguiente enlace:
https://t.me/share/url?url=AAAAAAAAA

De aqui leer la info del boton guardar el texto y luego sacar del texto el AAAAAAA y mandarlo a otro bot.

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer la sección [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Véase: Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

quizas esto te pueda servir.

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

web = https://t.me/share/url?url=AAAAAAAAA

descargamos el boton

web = requests.get(url)
```

convertimos la página para poder leerla

```
webtraducida = BeautifulSoup(web.content, 'html.parser')
```

capturamos la clase que nos interesa

```
siguientepaguina = webtraducida.find('div',class_="tgme_page_action")
```

apartir de aqui solo es recoger lo que deseas

```
print (siguientepaguina)
```